Change order of characters in cells , to another order same characters
i need to change multiple cells in excel
from this "17 - 2024 (c)" to this "(c) 2024 - 17"
where the 17 is pay periods so it can be 1-27
and there is 3 years of data 2021-2024
and will be adding  new data every pay period

What have you tried so far?

Thank you!
I should be able to do that

You could try using the following formula, basic formula, with the help of a LET() function:


=LET(
     a, TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),
     b, COLUMNS(a),
     c, SORTBY(a,-SEQUENCE(,b)),
     TEXTJOIN(" ",,c))



a split the string using TEXTSPLIT()
b count no of the columns the string is split into
c sort the split data in ascending order or descending order (remove the negative sign and set the order as -1),
Last but not least use the TEXTJOIN() function to join into one single pack.



Thank you! I should be able to do that

Here's one way to do it with 4 helper columns:

In the column next to your original data do: =TEXTSPLIT(A1," ") (assuming your original data starts in A1);
In the 5th column do: =TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,E1,D1,C1,B1)

If this is a one-time thing to do, this should work and you can then copy the last column (with the final results) and do special-paste -> values only, then delete the helper columns.

EDIT
If you're using Excel 365, you can use LET to do it with only one cell: =LET(_Split,TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),_Join,(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,CHOOSECOLS(_Split,4),KIES.KOLOMMEN(_Split,3),CHOOSECOLS(_Split,2),CHOOSECOLS(_Split,1))),_Join)

